# Scala Filter List[Int] Which Exists in other List of Tuples

Tags: list, scala

I've a two lists dest (contains:x) and points (x,y)

```
dest:List[Int] and Points:List[(Int,Int)]
```

I want to filter elements in the dest, if it exists in points **(x==points._1)** i

```
var newl:List[Int] = List()
for(x<-dest) if(!points.filter(_._1==x).isEmpty) newl=newl:+x
```

I feel like there must be a better concise way with exists but tuple making it complex. So whats the best way to do the above?

Comment: What you are looking for is probably [diff(that: collection.Seq[A]): List[A]](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.11.5/index.html#scala.collection.immutable.List@diff(that:Seq[A]):List[A])

Comment: In scala we tend not to use vars as much as possible. Note that in my answer I converted newl to a val instead

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here is a concise way:

```
val dest= List(1,2,4,5)
val points = List((1,3), (2,3) , (3,4))
val newl = dest.filter{d => points.exists(_._1 == d)} // returns List(1, 2)
```

The following is even better order of complexity wise:

```
val dest= List(1,2,4,5)
val points = List((1,3), (2,3) , (3,4))
val xs = points.map{_._1}.toSet
val newl = dest.filter(xs.contains(_))
```

Comment: You can even make it shorter by doing `val newl = dest.filter(xs)`, since the `apply` method on `Set` is the same as `contains`

Comment: `filter(points.map(_._1).toSet)` works but not `filter(points.map(_._1).toSet)`,  why? also whats the difference between the conventions `filter ()` and `filter {}`

Comment: They look same to me. There is no difference between () and {}. I think its just a convention to use {} when you are not using _